# Why i use this script my bot stops all commands (only admin works)

Tags: discord, discord.py

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send(f":x: {ctx.author.mention} Você prescisa de permissão!")
```

this is the script! help me. thanks!

Comment: do you have an `on_message` event?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a `on_message` event which is blocking you from processing the commands commands, you will need to process them, add this line at the end of your `on_message` event or share your whole code:

```
await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Reference: [`process_commands()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)

Comment: This is bad, you use this in the `on_message` event, not in an error handler.